# NoSuchElementError when element is actually there

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, selenium, protractor

I have this line in one of my angular tests:

```
element(by.id('male')).click();
```

And the test is failing with this message:

```
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.id("male")
```

But when I add `browser.sleep()` to the test I can see that there's `#male` element on the page.

So I tried adding explicit wait and it didn't help. What could be wrong?

Comment: the element you are trying to click on, is most likely inside of a frame.. could you verify?

Comment: also, could you tell us, whether or not the target element has an `id="male"`, or is it `name="male"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often use the following helper functions to wait for an element to be present or displayed. Maybe give them a try and Protractor will block until these return `true`. Maybe give them a go.

```
module.exports = {
    /**
     * Block until an element is displayed on the page.
     *
     * @param {object} elem
     * The element to watch for.
     *
     * @param {number} [customTimeout=10000]
     * How long to wait for `elem` to appear.
     */
    waitForElementToBeDisplayed: function (elem, customTimeout) {
        var timeout = customTimeout || 10000;
        browser.wait(function () {
            return elem.isDisplayed().then(
                function (visible) {
                    return visible;
                },
                function () {
                    return false;
                }
            );
        }, timeout, 'failed to find element ' + elem.locator());
    },

    /**
     * Block until an element is present on the page.
     *
     * @param {Object} elem
     * The element to watch for.
     *
     * @param {Number} [customTimeout=10000]
     * How long to wait for 'elem' to appear.
     */
    waitForElementToBePresent: function (elem, customTimeout) {
        var timeout = customTimeout || 10000;
        browser.wait(function () {
            return elem.isPresent().then(
                function (visible) {
                    return visible;
                },
                function () {
                    return false;
                }
            );
        }, timeout, 'Element not present: ' + elem.locator());
    }
}
```